# How to insert html & css into Outlook email?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to design a nicely formatted email using html.

I am embedding my html file through: Attach file ->> Select .html file ->> Insert as text

It does read my html, but somehow it does not recognize my internally inserted css into html.

Here is my basic html file with css in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color: red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I get on my screen (so, as you can see no red background is displayed)
[image]

Who knows what might be the problem? Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked up to ensure setting the background colour via CSS is allowed?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a mass email out, your better bet is to try to use a service such as MailChimp, Elastic Email, etc. or similar to get properly formatted html emails.

I have designed a few custom emails for a mail out before and its a big pain since different email clients will interpret your formatting differently (gmail, hotmail, etc.)

Hope that helps.